# Several JavaFX components into one stage

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I have a problem which I cannot solve. I create JavaFX project. I created main Java class which will call all components of the project:

```
public class SQLBrowser extends Application {

    // Menu Utilization
    CreatingMenus menu;
    // Navigation Utilization
    Navigation navigation;
    // Set window size, color, window label
    private final String windowLabel = "SQL Browser";
    private final int xSize = 1200;
    private final int ySize = 650;
    private final Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Set Label
        primaryStage.setTitle(windowLabel);

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, xSize, ySize, backgroundColor);

        // Generate menu from sqlbrowser.menu.CreatingMenus;
        menu = new CreatingMenus();
        menu.initMenu(primaryStage, root, scene);
        // Generate Data table navigation from sqlbrowser.navigation.Navigation;
        navigation = new Navigation();
        navigation.initNavigation(primaryStage, root, scene);


    }
}
```

I created simple menu into separate Java class:

```
public class CreatingMenus {

    // Generate Menu
    public void initMenu(final Stage primaryStage, Group root, Scene scene) {

        // Call Menu Actions from Java Method MenuActions
        final MenuActions ma = new MenuActions();

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();

        // File menu - new, save, close, exit
        Menu menu = new Menu("File");
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("New"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Save"));
        menu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Close"));
        menu.getItems().add(new SeparatorMenuItem());

        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

        // Exit from the application
        menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                // This Java Method is called from the Java Class MenuActions
                ma.programExit(); // Exit program
            }
        });

        menu.getItems().add(menuItem);

        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);

        // Options menu - Preferences
        Menu options = new Menu("Options");
        options.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Preferences"));

        menuBar.getMenus().add(options);

        // Help menu - About
        Menu help = new Menu("Help");

        MenuItem helpItem = new MenuItem("About");

        // Exit from the application
        helpItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                aboutDialog();
            }
        });

        help.getItems().add(helpItem);

        menuBar.getMenus().add(help);

        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());

        root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void aboutDialog() {

        final int xSize = 640;
        final int ySize = 480;
        final String logoImage = "/logo.png";
        final Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        final String text = "SQL Browser";
        final String version = "Product Version: 1.0";
        final String license = "License Information";

        final Stage aboutDialog = new Stage();
        aboutDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));

        // Logo
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(logoImage));
        ImageView logo = new ImageView(image);

        grid.add(logo, 1, 0);

        // Product name
        Text productName = new Text(text);
        productName.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productName, 0, 2);

        // Product version
        Text productVersion = new Text(version);
        productVersion.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productVersion, 0, 3);

        // Product License
        Text productLicense = new Text(license);
        productLicense.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 12));
        grid.add(productLicense, 0, 4);

        // Close Button
        Button closeButton = new Button("Close");

        closeButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Close the dialog when "Close" button is pressed
                aboutDialog.close();
            }
        });
        grid.add(closeButton, 5, 18);

        // Configure dialog size and background color
        Scene aboutDialogScene = new Scene(grid, xSize, ySize, backgroundColor);
        aboutDialog.setScene(aboutDialogScene);
        aboutDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Then I added accordion component which will be used for navigation:

```
public class Navigation {

    private static final Image BLUE_FISH = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/fish-toys/128/Blue-Fish-icon.png");
    private static final Image RED_FISH = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/fish-toys/128/Red-Fish-icon.png");
    private static final Image YELLOW_FISH = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/fish-toys/128/Yellow-Fish-icon.png");
    private static final Image GREEN_FISH = new Image("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/fish-toys/128/Green-Fish-icon.png");

    public void initNavigation(Stage primaryStage, Group root, Scene scene) {

        VBox stackedTitledPanes = createStackedTitledPanes();

        ScrollPane scroll = makeScrollable(stackedTitledPanes);
        scroll.getStyleClass().add("stacked-titled-panes-scroll-pane");
        scroll.setPrefSize(410, 480);
        scroll.setLayoutX(0);
        scroll.setLayoutY(20);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Fishy, fishy");
        scene = new Scene(scroll);
        //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("fishy-fishy.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private VBox createStackedTitledPanes() {
        final VBox stackedTitledPanes = new VBox();
        stackedTitledPanes.getChildren().setAll(
                createTitledPane("One Fish", GREEN_FISH),
                createTitledPane("Two Fish", YELLOW_FISH, GREEN_FISH),
                createTitledPane("Red Fish", RED_FISH),
                createTitledPane("Blue Fish", BLUE_FISH));
        ((TitledPane) stackedTitledPanes.getChildren().get(0)).setExpanded(true);
        stackedTitledPanes.getStyleClass().add("stacked-titled-panes");

        return stackedTitledPanes;
    }

    public TitledPane createTitledPane(String title, Image... images) {
        FlowPane content = new FlowPane();
        for (Image image : images) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
            content.getChildren().add(imageView);

            FlowPane.setMargin(imageView, new Insets(10));
        }
        content.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        TitledPane pane = new TitledPane(title, content);
        pane.getStyleClass().add("stacked-titled-pane");
        pane.setExpanded(false);

        return pane;
    }

    private ScrollPane makeScrollable(final VBox node) {
        final ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setContent(node);
        scroll.viewportBoundsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Bounds>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> ov, Bounds oldBounds, Bounds bounds) {
                node.setPrefWidth(bounds.getWidth());
            }
        });
        return scroll;
    }
}
```

But for some unknown reason I get this result:

[image]

for some reason the menu is not displayed and the size of the window is changed. Can you tell me how I can fix this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initMethods, instead of setting the scene again and again to the stage, and even creating a new one. I recommend you to add to a container: [here it is a tutorial about layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/jfxpub-layout.htm).

And replacing your main class to something like:

```
    VBox root = new VBox();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    // Generate menu from sqlbrowser.menu.CreatingMenus;
    menu = new CreatingMenus();
    menu.initMenu(primaryStage, root);
    // Generate Data table navigation from sqlbrowser.navigation.Navigation;
    navigation = new Navigation();
    navigation.initNavigation(primaryStage, root);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, xSize, ySize, backgroundColor);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

And in your initMethods, removing the scene, because you shouldn't use it inside, and adding the Nodes that you are generating to the Container, in this example a VBox.

```
public void initMenu(final Stage primaryStage, VBox root) {
   ....
   root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
}

public void initNavigation(Stage primaryStage, VBox root) {
   ....
   root.getChildren().add(scroll);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In your Example you overwrite your Scene!

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Fishy, fishy");
// this line are wrong!
scene = new Scene(scroll);
//scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("fishy-fishy.css").toExternalForm());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```

You should use one scene and one main layout.

Comment: You'll find many examples [here](http://java-buddy.blogspot.de/) or [here](http://translate.google.de/translate?sl=de&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=de&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.axxg.de%2Fcategory%2Fprogrammierung%2Fjava%2Fjavafx%2F&act=url)